# Ошибка ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'schedule'

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, pythonanywhere

Вот основной код:

```py
NAME = 'БОТ JASON'
VERSION = 1.0
# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// ИМПОРТ МОДУЛЕЙ /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import schedule
# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// КОНЕЦ ИМПОРТА МОДУЛЕЙ /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// МАССИВЫ С ID БЕСЕД И УЧИТЕЛЕЙ /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
ids_group = [ # Не знаю почему назвал группами беседу, да и кого это волнует))
    2000000014, # Русский язык
    2000000018, # Обществознание
    2000000017, # Физика
    2000000015, # История
    2000000016, # Биология
    2000000019, # Английский язык
]

# учителя
ids_teachers = [
    159523091, # Назиля (Русский язык)
    37066446, # Диляра (Обществознание)
    88864448, # Анвар (Физика)
    105722192, # Оля (История)
    241310331, # Антонина (Биология)
    44618787, # Регина(Английский язык)
]
# те кому можно все
ids_can_all = [
    333017994, # Равиль
    23526696, # Альберт
    504785497, # Санчай
]
# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// КОНЕЦ МАССИВОВ С ID БЕСЕД И УЧИТЕЛЕЙ /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// ФУНКЦИИ /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


# Вывод сообщений
def send_message(peer_id, message):
    vk.messages.send(
        peer_id=peer_id,
        message=message,
        random_id=get_random_id(),
    )

# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
# *********** Функция призыва ***********
def prizyv_rus():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = 2000000014,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Призыв!'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000014, message)

# *********** Функция вызова за час ***********
def prizyv_hour_rus():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = 2000000014,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Всем привет! Хочу напомнить что через час у вас вебинар. За 10 минут до начала вебинара я скину вам ссылку.'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000014, message)




# *********** Функция вызова за 10 минут ***********
def prizyv_10minute_rus():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = 2000000014,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Итак, ровно через 10 минут начинается вебинар! Вот вам ссылка: *Тут ссылка*. Всем удачи!!!!!'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000014, message)

# *************** Будильник по утрам *******************
def prizyv_rus_morning():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = 2000000014,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Доброе утро! Хочу напомнить вам что сегодня вебинар. Всем хорошего дня ❤❤❤'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000014, message)

# //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// ОБЩЕСТВОЗНАНИЕ /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
# *********** Функция призыва ***********
def prizyv_obsch():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = 2000000018,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Призыв!'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000018, message)

# *********** Функция вызова за час ***********
def prizyv_hour_obsch():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = 2000000018,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Всем привет! Хочу напомнить что через час у вас вебинар. За 10 минут до начала вебинара я скину вам ссылку.'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000018, message)




# *********** Функция вызова за 10 минут ***********
def prizyv_10minute_obsch():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = 2000000018,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Итак, ровно через 10 минут начинается вебинар! Вот вам ссылка: *Тут ссылка*. Всем удачи!!!!!'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000018, message)

# *************** Будильник по утрам *******************
def prizyv_obsch_morning():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = 2000000018,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Доброе утро! Хочу напомнить вам что сегодня вебинар. Всем хорошего дня ❤❤❤'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000018, message)
# //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// ФИЗИКА /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
# *********** Функция призыва ***********
def prizyv_phys():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = 2000000017,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Призыв!'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000017, message)

# *********** Функция вызова за час ***********
def prizyv_hour_phys():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = 2000000017,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Всем привет! Хочу напомнить что через час у вас вебинар. За 10 минут до начала вебинара я скину вам ссылку.'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000017, message)


# *********** Функция вызова за 10 минут ***********
def prizyv_10minute_phys():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = 2000000017,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Итак, ровно через 10 минут начинается вебинар! Вот вам ссылка: *Тут ссылка*. Всем удачи!!!!!'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000017, message)

# *************** Будильник по утрам *******************
def prizyv_phys_morning():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = 2000000017,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Доброе утро! Хочу напомнить вам что сегодня вебинар. Всем хорошего дня ❤❤❤'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000017, message)
# //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// ИСТОРИЯ /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
# *********** Функция призыва ***********
def prizyv_history():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = 2000000015,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Призыв!'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000015, message)
# *********** Функция вызова за час ***********
def prizyv_hour_history():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = 2000000015,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Всем привет! Хочу напомнить что через час у вас вебинар. За 10 минут до начала вебинара я скину вам ссылку.'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000015, message)




# *********** Функция вызова за 10 минут ***********
def prizyv_10minute_history():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = 2000000015,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Итак, ровно через 10 минут начинается вебинар! Вот вам ссылка: *Тут ссылка*. Всем удачи!!!!!'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000015, message)
# *************** Будильник по утрам *******************
def prizyv_history_morning():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = 2000000015,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Доброе утро! Хочу напомнить вам что сегодня вебинар. Всем хорошего дня ❤❤❤'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000015, message)

# //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// БИОЛОГИЯ /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
# *********** Функция призыва ***********
def prizyv_bio():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = 2000000016,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Призыв!'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000016, message)
# *********** Функция вызова за час ***********
def prizyv_hour_bio():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = 2000000016,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Всем привет! Хочу напомнить что через час у вас вебинар. За 10 минут до начала вебинара я скину вам ссылку.'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000016, message)

# *************** Будильник по утрам *******************
def prizyv_bio_morning():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = 2000000016,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Доброе утро! Хочу напомнить вам что сегодня вебинар. Всем хорошего дня ❤❤❤'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000016, message)


# *********** Функция вызова за 10 минут ***********
def prizyv_10minute_bio():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = 2000000016,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Итак, ровно через 10 минут начинается вебинар! Вот вам ссылка: *Тут ссылка*. Всем удачи!!!!!'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000016, message)


# //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// ENGLISH /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
# *********** Функция призыва ***********
def prizyv_eng():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = 2000000019,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Призыв!'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000019, message)
# *********** Функция вызова за час ***********
def prizyv_hour_eng():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = 2000000019,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Всем привет! Хочу напомнить что через час у вас вебинар. За 10 минут до начала вебинара я скину вам ссылку.'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000019, message)

# *************** Будильник по утрам *******************
def prizyv_eng_morning():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = 2000000019,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Доброе утро! Хочу напомнить вам что сегодня вебинар. Всем хорошего дня ❤❤❤'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000019, message)


# *********** Функция вызова за 10 минут ***********
def prizyv_10minute_eng():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id = 2000000019,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Итак, ровно через 10 минут начинается вебинар! Вот вам ссылка: *Тут ссылка*. Всем удачи!!!!!'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000019, message)


# //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////





def messforall():
    for event in longPoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            from_id in ids_can_all  # id пользователя, который отправил сообщение
            peer_id in ids_group  # peer_id беседы или ЛС, откуда пришло сообщение

            # lower - это метод приведения к нижнему регистру. Для регистронезависимости.
            message = event.obj['text'].lower()

            # message теперь в нижнем регистре, поэтому все проверки делаем тоже в нижнем регистре
            if '#' in message and from_id in ids_can_all:
                message1 = message
                for i in range(len(ids_group)):
                    send_message(ids_group[i], message1)
        return ''




# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// КОНЕЦ ФУНКЦИЙ /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Планировщик /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

# теги: rus, eng, phys, bio, history, obsch
def scheduler():
    #Будильник по утрам
    schedule.every().sunday.at("08:00").do(prizyv_rus_morning)
    schedule.every().sunday.at("08:00").do(prizyv_obsch_morning)
    schedule.every().sunday.at("08:00").do(prizyv_phys_morning)
    schedule.every().sunday.at("08:00").do(prizyv_history_morning)
    schedule.every().sunday.at("08:00").do(prizyv_bio_morning)
    schedule.every().sunday.at("08:00").do(prizyv_eng_morning)
    #Физика
    schedule.every().sunday.at("11:00").do(prizyv_hour_phys)
    schedule.every().sunday.at("11:50").do(prizyv_10minute_phys)
    #Биология
    schedule.every().sunday.at("12:00").do(prizyv_hour_phys)
    schedule.every().sunday.at("12:50").do(prizyv_10minute_phys)
    #Химия
    schedule.every().sunday.at("13:00").do(prizyv_hour_phys)
    schedule.every().sunday.at("13:50").do(prizyv_10minute_phys)
    #История
    schedule.every().sunday.at("14:00").do(prizyv_hour_phys)
    schedule.every().sunday.at("14:50").do(prizyv_10minute_phys)
    #Обществознание
    schedule.every().sunday.at("15:00").do(prizyv_hour_phys)
    schedule.every().sunday.at("15:50").do(prizyv_10minute_phys)
    #Английский язык
    schedule.every().sunday.at("16:00").do(prizyv_hour_phys)
    schedule.every().sunday.at("16:50").do(prizyv_10minute_phys)
    #Русский язык
    schedule.every().sunday.at("17:00").do(prizyv_hour_phys)
    schedule.every().sunday.at("17:50").do(prizyv_10minute_phys)

    schedule.every().day.at("19:50").do(prizyv_10minute_eng)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        sleep(1)  # Выберите оптимальное значение под свои задачи планировщика

# Создаём и запускаем планировщик в отдельном потоке
t = Thread(target=scheduler)
t.start()


# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Конец планировщика /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ БОТА /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


accessToken = '' # токен
groupId = 183464879  # id группы в котором находится бот

vkBotSession = VkApi(token=accessToken)
longPoll = VkBotLongPoll(vkBotSession, groupId)
vk = vkBotSession.get_api()


# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// КОНЕЦ РЕГИСТРАЦИИ БОТА /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// САМА РАБОТА БОТА В БЕСЕДАХ /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


for event in longPoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        """
        Если бот не отвечает на сообщения из беседы, то выдайте ему права
        на чтение всей переписки, а лучше сразу права администратора,
        потому что они нужны для функции prizyv.
        """
        from_id = event.obj['from_id']  # id пользователя, который отправил сообщение
        peer_id = event.obj['peer_id']  # peer_id беседы или ЛС, откуда пришло сообщение

        # lower - это метод приведения к нижнему регистру. Для регистронезависимости.
        message = event.obj['text'].lower()

        # message теперь в нижнем регистре, поэтому все проверки делаем тоже в нижнем регистре
        # теги: rus, eng, phys, bio, history, obsch
        if ('крут' in message) and message != 'полностью согласен! реально круто ':
            send_message(peer_id, 'О да, это точно круто! B-)')
        elif (message == 'призыв!') and (from_id == 159523091):
            prizyv_rus()
        elif (message == 'призыв!') and (from_id == 37066446):
            prizyv_obsch()
        elif (message == 'призыв!') and (from_id == 88864448):
            prizyv_phys()
        elif (message == 'призыв!') and (from_id == 105722192):
            prizyv_history()
        elif (message == 'призыв!') and (from_id == 241310331):
            prizyv_bio()
        elif (message == 'призыв!') and (from_id == 44618787):
            prizyv_eng()
        elif (message == 'общий призыв!') and (from_id in ids_can_all):
            prizyv_rus()
            prizyv_obsch()
            prizyv_phys()
            prizyv_history()
            prizyv_bio()
            prizyv_eng()
            messforall()
#//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

В качестве хостинга использую [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/)

При запуске программы выдает `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'schedule'`

В отдельном Bash консоле вводил команды и скачал

```bash
pip install schedule
pip install vk_api
```

В чем может быть проблема? У меня все хорошо работает. Вводил у себя в компьютере те же команды что и выше.

Comment: Проблема в том, что на сервере нет модуля schedule ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Совпадает ли версия питона из `pip --version` с `python --version`? Часто бывает, что `pip` относится ко второму питону, к третьему - `pip3`

Comment: Спасибо! не совпадала версия pip и python. Нужно было написать pip3 install --user schedule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не совпадала версия pip и python. Нужно было написать `pip3 install --user schedule`.